# First batch result

Tags: first-time-brewer, malt, chocolate

I'm know enjoying my first batch of beer. I think, it will be some kinda use for those who are hesitating to start their brew or still researching. I did quite much research before i did brew.

During brew day I was much afraid of contaminating wort. It happened at some level but finished beer is ok. I will explain how.

First, I malted my own barley and roasted it. It took me quite long time to malt 5 kg of barley at home conditions.

Secondly, I thought that crushing malt with roller pin would gave me the same output as malt mill but I was mistaken. As a result, half of the malt wasn't cracked at all. I found out about it after brew by observing steeped malt. So, my advice here is that you better use grain mill, or blender if you don't have a mill.

Thirdly, It took me about 40-50 minutes to cool down 15Lof hot wort from 100C to 22C in cold bath. As I don't have a wort chiller. My advice: buy or make one for yourself. Unfortunately, I added some 5L more water but it lowered gravity. My advice is not to overadjust gravity of your wort. Do it little by little.

Fourthly, I did sanitation with StarSan while cooling wort down. However, I got infection somehow. The wort didn't ferment much, only 5-7 days then it stopped. But i didn't touch it until 14 days after sealing it. Bottled beer with brown sugar, it worked well.

Fifthly, I had ordered wort racking cane late, therefore I had to pour wort from carboy glass to bottles through cotton and cloth filter but it was inefficient. Some of the yeast got into bottles. Do not repeat my mistake.
After 2 weeks I tasted my beer. It was well carbonated, around 1.5% alcohol and some sour taste. I did research about sour taste, it happens bcoz of infection from cold side of storage. Full article here:

https://beerandbrewing.com/ask-the-experts-source-of-unintentional-sour-flavors-in-beer/?utm_campaign=editorial&utm_medium=email&utm_source=autopilot&utm_content=sticke-altbier
In general, i am happy with my first result. I was afraid to ruin everything.

Here is the recipe:

4.5kg caramel malt (malted and roasted myself)
0.5kg dark malt malted and roasted myself)
1 bar of dark chocolate
30gr Sapphire hops at 60 min
30gr Sapphire hops at 30 min
30gr Sapphire hops at 0 min
1 tbsp of baker's yeasts. 
20L water during step mashing
5L water after boil 
Result:
Aroma: Chocolate, nutty, citrus
Flavor: Sour, chocolate,
Color: reddish-brown

[image][image]

Comment: Gratz on your first brew! However you don't ask a question, so you may not get many answers. It will be very difficult for others to benifiet from your experience in this format.

Comment: Just wanted to share my experience ;)

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard of anyone malting their own barley.  That is really cool.

Comment: Congrats on the beer. Any questions?

Comment: You really need to have a question due to the Q&A nature of the site. If you don't ask a question this is likely to be flagged to the moderating team and removed.

Comment: @freshop Malting barley is harder than brewing beer. I think, that's why most people don't go that way.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry not really an answer but wanted to say, wow! malting your own barley. That is definitely taking it to the next level for sure. It sounds like you have the passion and excitement to make this a long term affair. Welcome to the brewing family. I've made a few batches of beer that "only it's brewer could palate", and thankfully only one or two that "fertilized the garden". Keep it up and good luck.